# couchrest_model - how to drop a database?

Tags: ruby, couchrest

I want to be able to start my tests pointing at a non-existant couchdb database, so that I can test from a blank canvas. How should I do this?

```
describe MyCouchModel do
  before :all do
    described_class.drop # This doesn't work!
  end

  it 'should be empty' do
    described-class.all.length.should == 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this inside some tests for another library:

```
MyCouchModel.database.delete!
```

So in a test you could do:

```
describe MyCouchModel do
  before :all do
    described_class.database.delete!
    described_class.database.create!
  end
end
```

Comment: The delete bang method works fine for deleting databases. You might also want to look at the CouchRest Model specs for a more generic approach that might be suitable for testing:

https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb#L28